# Pig step execution details

Tags: apache-pig

I am newbee to pig .

I have written a small script in pig , where in i first load the data from two different tables and further right outer join the two tables ,later also i have next join of tables for two different st of data  .It works fine .But i want to see
the steps of execution , like in which step my data is loaded that way i can note the time
needed for loading later details of step for **data joining** like how much time it is 
taking for these much records to be joined .

Basically i want to know which part of my pig script is taking longer time to run so
that way i can further optimize my pig script .

Anyway we could println within the script and find which steps got executed which has started to execute .

Through jobtracker details link i could not get much info , just could see mapper is running & reducer is running , but idealy mapper for which part of script is running could not find that.

For example for a hive job run we can see in the jobtracker details link which step is currently getting executed.

Any information will be really helpfull.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to have a look at the followings:

- Pig's [Progress Notification Listener](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/test.html#ppnl)
- [Penny](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/Penny) : this is a monitoring tool but I'm afraid that it hasn't been updated in the recent past (e.g: it won't compile for Pig 0.12.0 unless you do some code changes)
- Twitter's Ambrose project. https://github.com/twitter/ambrose

On the other, after executing the script you can see a detailed statistics about the execution time of each alias (see: *Job Stats (time in seconds)*).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`EXPLAIN` operator](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/developing_and_testing.html).  This doesn't give you real-time stats as your code is executing, but it should give you enough information about the MapReduce plan your script generates that you'll be able to match up the MR jobs with the steps in your script.

Also, while your script is running you can inspect the configuration of the Hadoop job.  Look at the variables "pig.alias" and "pig.job.feature".  These tell you, respectively, which of your aliases (tables/relations) is involved in that job and what Pig operations are being used (e.g., HASH_JOIN for a `JOIN` step, SAMPLER or ORDER BY for an `ORDER BY` step, and so on).  This information is also available in the job stats that are output to the console upon completion.

Comment: Thank you so much all above .I will further try with working on above mentioned options.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't found the EXPLAIN operator before! See also the ILLUSTRATE command. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/test.html